# Get specific column of specific user in datatable

Tags: c#, datatable

I have a data table, in the data table, I have 3 columns: USERNAME, PASSWORD, and Money.

I want to make a specific setting in my program to make a label the amount of money the user has, and for each user, it will show something else depending on who is logged on at the moment, is it possible and if yes how can I do it?

Thanks in advance.

[image: Database layout]

Comment: Hi, can you provide some of the code you've tried? This will allow people to see how you're working, as there are so many ways to answer this question. If i provide you with an answer that binds to an xaml property, it may not help you :(

Comment: Idk how to write the code in a box, srry.
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\gabri\Documents\data.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30");
            SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter("Select Count (*) From Login where Username='" + textBox1.Text + "' and Password ='" + textBox2.Text + "'", con);
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            sda.Fill(dt);
            if (dt.Rows[0][0].ToString() == "1")
            {
                //Do something             
            }

Comment: @Retr0 You should include this code *in the question*, not in a comment. You can format it properly there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can put the amount of money in your label by writing some code. This is used for MSSQL Database connections(in your case).
Here is an example:

```
using System.Data.SqlClient;//Add this in the using statements at the top of your code.

using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source = (LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB; AttachDbFilename =" +Application.StartupPath+ @"\Database1.mdf; Integrated Security = True"))
        {
            conn.Open();
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand())
            {
                cmd.Connection = conn;
                cmd.CommandText = "SELECT Money FROM Users WHERE Username = @username";

                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", "User1");

                var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                reader.Read();

                label1.Text = reader.GetValue(0).ToString(); //reader returns an object, you have to convert it in your type.
                //GetValue(selected column number)
            }
            conn.Close();//This line is optional. The connection closes automatically when the using() statement ends.
        }
```

You can add this code in your Form Load event.(If you are working with Win Forms).

The second method is to use Dataset with binding the label to it. This is also powerful and you do not need to know too much sql or how to code, it is more complicated at the beginning but it`s easier and saves time. You can apply it to any of your form elements(buttons, datagridviews,combobox,textbox,etc).

First, go to your label properties and find "DataBindings". Click on advanced. Just click next until you see the connect to database option. If your are connected already with visual studio to your database it will appear in that combobox, otherwise click new connection(I suppose you worked in service based database).Click next and finish. After you have to bind the label to the database(it will create a generated code in your Form Load Event). If you have only one record(one user) in the table it will show only one value, but if you want to show a specific user, you can change that "Fill" generated method in your Form Load Event in other(filtered one with WHERE SQL Clause). You can change that fill method in the Dataset Added in the bottom of your designer of the form. Click on that little arrow near it and choose "edit in designer" option. Click on the table adapter section and right click on his function(in this case Fill() method) and click configure. Here you can change the sql statement and put a WHERE clause in the end.(ex Where Username = ?) The "?" means some variable. After pass in the function created in the form load event your user`s username next to that dataset thing. Done. If you want to work with Win Forms and sql databases I advise you to learn how to use The Datasets, Bindings and TableAdapters. Hope it helps.
Screenshots of my explanations:

[image: Step1]
[image: Step2]
[image: Step3]
[image: Step4]
[image: Step5]
[image: Step6]
[image: Step7]
[image: Step8]
[image: Step9]

!!!! [UPDATE] !!!!
Here is my example program on google drive: [Link](https://drive.google.com/open?id=16fJ7jjykVyIOWs564EPIWOcRsK8mGKPY).
On the right side you can open my service based database(in the project files(Database1)).I'll attach some useful screenshots for creating addition functions in a dataset's table adaper. Also, you have the second method commented in the Form1 load event.

[image: Img1]
[image: Img2]
[image: Img3]
[image: Img4]
[image: Img5]
[image: Img6]
[image: Img7]

Comment: I tried your second way, for some reason the label which supposed to have the money doesn't show anything, just an empty label, did I do something wrong?

Comment: It should work, you missed something. It is quite hard to explain those things, please search the internet for a better understanding, or work with first method. I will attach a drive link with an example program. It will appear at the end of my pictures.

Comment: Thank you for updating your answer, the second method did work, but I get here into a small thing, I have in my win form a register location, and when I try to sign in with different account that I just made my money is still the same as for the first user, do I need to add the users into the code manually?

Comment: Please tell me more about what you want to do. This is what I understand: You have a win form application where you can register and login and when you switch accounts your money is the same? You have to run that function in the form load event when you want your data to change. For example you have to change the user's username in the method(From User1 to your new user).

Comment: Yes, My win form has a registration  place where you register and after that you are free to log in (the register saves to the database) and whenever I log in it still gives me the money of let's say "Retr0" While I'm logged in as "John"

Comment: Like I said, every time you log in, you have to specify in that function(method) the user that you are currently logged in and your values will update. For example, every time when you click the LogIn button you have to run that this.usersTableAdapter.FillByUsername(this.database1.DataSet.Users, <logged in user's username>)

Comment: Thank you for all of your help! I found a way that I already used that was putting the username in Properties.settings.default.Loggedin and using this as a way to know which user is currently logged on, Thank you for all of your help!