# Retrieving data into textbox from database

Tags: c#, sql-server

The text of `Label1` doesn't change, what could be the cause of this issue?

```cs
try
{
    string connectionString = @"Data Source = (localdb)\MSSQLLocalDB; Initial Catalog = db1; Integrated Security = True";
    SqlConnection cnn = new SqlConnection(connectionString);

    string query = "SELECT RNO FROM TABLE1 WHERE RNO='" + PRrno.Text + "'";

    SqlCommand cd = new SqlCommand(query, cnn);
    cnn.Open();

    SqlDataReader reader = cd.ExecuteReader();

    while (reader.Read())
    {
        Label1.Text = reader["RNO"].ToString();
    }

    reader.Close();
    cnn.Close();
}
```

Comment: In order to help you more code is required, such as the declaration of `Label1` and so on.

Comment: What's the point of the query? You select `RNO` field from the table where `RNO` has a certain value. The query will return the value that your are looking for or an empty result if the value does not exist in the table.

Comment: I guess you are using webforms/aspx, if so, make sure your textbox and form have the attribute runat="server" as follows: 

<form runat="server">

<asp:TextBox id="PRrno" runat="server" />

Comment: @IvanLopez What makes you think that the OP uses webforms?

Comment: @shadow Cause SqlDataReaders were pretty common with webforms, besides that in webforms you refer your UI components by their name in the code behind file just like PRrno.Text

Comment: Also, pls make sure that you use the appropriate tags! Mysql and ms sql server are two different products!

Comment: @IvanLopez data readers are common in every database driven .net application and form controls are referred to by their names in pretty much every .net gui...

Comment: @shadow datareaders are not very common since EF became popular, and form controls referred by their names are pretty much in every .net GUI is not totally accurate (if web he could use a non .net ui), could be webforms (like I said), windows forms and XAML, the only difference is that only webforms and XAML could have issues with binding.

Comment: @IvanLopez so, the code could equally be a winform or a xaml application :) we simply have no clue what this code is.

Comment: @shadow if he is getting a value from the DB, winforms doesn't have issues with binding, and in XAML the UI objects are bound by a property not referring the UI element, that makes me guess he is using webforms, but he has to reply back.

Comment: well to clarify the doubts, this is c# aspx and webform, PRrno is a textbox, everything is accessible and this is just a sample code and I'm just trying to get this done! Absolutely there is no point of the query as its just the check if it works or not. I would update the code as per the requirements later on. what do you suggest i do so that the value of the label gets changed?

Comment: I have answered to a similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60177889/11694619

Answer (score 0):

Gaurav Thapa, like I said in one of the comments, make sure in the aspx file your elements have runat="server" also put all the elements you want to get refreshed inside an Ajax Update Panel

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="_Default" %>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml11/DTD/xhtml11.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title>UpdatePanel</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server" />
        <asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" id="UpdatePanel" updatemode="Always">        
            <ContentTemplate>
                <asp:Label runat="server" id="PRrno" />
            </ContentTemplate>
        </asp:UpdatePanel>       
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -2):

You have to get query output in data table and then from there convert that DataTable value to string.
Check if you have access to your label.

Label.Text = // String that you converted from DataTable